# Similar triangles in pinhole camera

Tags: geometry

I am trying to understand how we concluded below that the two triangles in pinhole camera example below are similar? What rule we used to conclude they are similar please (AA, SAS, SSS)?

[image]

Then we conclude from similar triangles that:

$$\frac{\lambda}{z} = \frac{v}{y}$$

Comment: SAS and SSS usually show triangles are congruent, not merely similar. The triangles in your diagram don't look congruent, and the triangles for a pinhole camera usually aren't. And I think the diagram leaves out details that certain angles are right angles.

Comment: @aschepler. Thanks. Do you mean from 1 and 2 in the figure, we can use AA rule to conclude they are similar?

Comment: If two pairs of angles are congruent then all corresponding angles are congruent in two triangles so the triangles are similar

Comment: @Vasili. Thanks. Why we assumed that we have a right triangle in pinhole camera in the first place?

Comment: The right triangles are by construction.

Comment: If $y$ and $v$ are distances, those angles have to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image side of the camera is the surface the image is being projected on. $\lambda$ is the distance from that surface to the pinhole. That distance is measured perpendicular to the surface, so the line from that surface to the pinhole is at a right angle to the surface. This establishes the vertical and horizontal directions.

$z$ is then the *horizontal* distance from the pinhole to the source, and $y$ is the *vertical* distance. This is the definition of these two values. And that is why the angle they form is also a right angle. Combine this with the vertical (as in "vertex-ical", not upward direction) angles being the same gives you the AA case for proving the triangles are similar and the indicated ratio must hold.